# Slow creation of four-field index in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a ProductRequest collection in MongoDB. It is somewhat large collection, but not that many documents. Number of documents is a bit over 300,000, but average size of a document is close to 1MB, thus data footprint is large.

To speed up certain queries I am setting up index on this collection:

```
db.ProductRequest.ensureIndex ({processed: 1, parsed: 1, error:1,processDate:1})
```

First three fields are Boolean, the last one is date time.

The command runs for soon 24 hours and would not come back

I already have index on ‘processed’ and  ‘parsed’ fields (together) and a separate one on ‘error’. Why creation of that four-field index takes forever? My understanding is that size of an individual record should not matter in this case, am I wrong?

Additional Info:

MongoDB version 2.6.1  64-bit

Host OS Centos 6.5

Sharding: yes, shard key is _id. Number of shards: 2, number of replica sets in each shard is 3.

Comment: Are you sure your terminal connection isn't simply gone away? Have you tried to check wether the index exists in a second mongo client?

Answer (score 0):

I **belive** its because of putting index for boolean fields.
since there are only two values (true or false), if you have 300.000 rows putting an index on that field will have to scan 150.00 rows to find all documents and in your case you have 3 Boolean fields, it makes it more slow.

Answer (score 0):

You won't see a huge benefit from an index on those three fields and `processDate` compared to an index just on `processDate`. Indexes on boolean fields aren't very useful in the presence of other index-able fields because they aren't very selective. If you give a process date, there are only 8 possibilities for the combination of the other fields to further narrow down the results via the index.

Also, you should switch the order. Put `processDate` first as it is much more selective than a boolean field. That should greatly simplify the index and speed up the index build.

Finally, index creation in MongoDB is sometimes unavoidably slow and expensive because it involves creating large B-trees. The payoff, which is absolutely worth it, of course, is faster queries. It's possible that more than 24 hours are needed for an index build. Have you checked what the saturated resource is? It's likely the CPU for an index build. Your best option for this case is to create the index [in the background](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/). Background index builds

- don't block read and write operation for the duration like foreground index builds
- take longer
- produce initially larger indexes that will converge to the size of an equivalent foreground index over time

You set an index build to occur in the background with an extra option to the `ensureIndex` call:

```
db.myCollection.ensureIndex({ "myField" : 1 }, { "background" : 1 })
```